# What is the difference between\"%s\" and "%s" in SQL code

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I've been trying to figure out the difference in usage of the " \ " characters in SQL.

For example a supplied line of code goes:

```
...  WHERE username=\"%s\" AND id=%s"
```

What would adding the " \ " character imply?

Comment: In SQLite this is simply wrong and would not even run. I suspect that this is snippet is written inside a program of a programming language other than SQL.

Comment: I would assume this is a byproduct of using string (concatenation) in whatever language you're writing that SQL inside to add the necessary quotes. It's certainly not something that SQL wants. Basically, I would assume that final quote there signals the end of a string, and the `\"` parts inside means to insert a quote character into the string, instead of ending the string. Again, this is in the programming language you're using to probably query the SQL database with, and not something for SQL.

Comment: Yes, it is a snippet, and not part of the full code line. (if it helps it is written in C, to query SQLite)

Comment: Then this is not a question about SQLite. You should tag it C and post the C code.

Comment: That screams very low quality code.

Comment: As a sidenote, most SQL libraries allow safe escaping of strings using parameters, so this snippet should be `WHERE username=:theusername  AND id=:theid`, then set `parameter("theusername")..` etc to the needed. This prevents SQL injection in code.

Comment: The code was meant to be vulnerable to SQL injection, I was thinking that this could be the reason why it is vulnerable. 

My thought process -> Would not having the \ character mean escaping the parameter and injecting additional code?

Comment: Is this the SQL a sent to SQLite, like from SQLite logs? Or is it a string in the C code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is C code like...

```
char sql[] = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE username=\"%s\" AND id=%s";
```

It is simply escaping the `"` character so it does not end the string. The resulting SQL is...

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE username="%s" AND id=%s
```

---

Aside from the [obvious problem of using string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) there is an additional vulnerability.

String literals use `'`. Using `"` indicates a an *identifier* like a table or column name. If no such identifier exists, SQLite will assume it is a string literal. An attacker could take advantage of this by supplying a value which matches an identifier.

SQLite provides this ambiguity in both directions.

> - If a keyword in single quotes (ex: 'key' or 'glob') is used in a context where an identifier is allowed but where a string literal is not allowed, then the token is understood to be an identifier instead of a string literal.
> - If a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string literal instead of an identifier.